# How do I Make a Spawner for Enemies in my Game?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm making my first zombie game in the Blender Game Engine. It is a first-person-shooter style game with zombies and stuff like that.

I am having trouble making an enemy spawner for the zombies however. I got it working somewhat before but after a certain amount of time the zombies just start to stack up on top of each other because I cannot get it to only spawn the zombies at the start of the game and after one dies. I changed it up some but now they don't spawn at all.

It really would be nice to have zombies spawn randomly within a specific area of the game but far away from the player. I don't know how to code in python so I'm making my game only with logic bricks. I have an `empty` currently that is supposed to spawn the zombies but it doesn't work.

Can you please help? You can download the game here: [Undead Fields](https://github.com/CadenMitchell/Undead_Fields/blob/master/Documents/Blender/Horror_Game.blend)

Comment: making a game only with logic bricks will be quite hard and challenging.

Comment: Luckily I've gotten pretty far over the past few days! I'm sure there's a way. I just dont know how. With a recent version I was able to get a spawner working pretty well. It would spawn a zombie if the player was far away and if there were no zombies by it. I however would prefer something that would detect if there was a max amount of zombies on screen and if not it would fill in for the extras by putting them in a random place in a set zone. If I need a script for this that's fine, as long as it's a copy/paste sort of thing.

Comment: I also think you will find a way with logic bricks but you may want to learn using scripts because they will make your work much easier. GL

Comment: Is there a sensor to detect a max amount of objects? I would really probably only need that and it might work.

Comment: I keep getting this error in the console `Warning, object "Empty.014" from AddObject actuator "Edit Object" is not in a hidden layer.` even after moving that object to a hidden layer

Comment: Strange. I tried making an updated version of this. Maybe that'll work.

Comment: Try this version. It's a bit different but it is working on my computer. (It's not on GitHub because I barely know how to use it!)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5LVYjOK5wy6TGV4ZzZ0V0NFczA

Answer (score 1):

As non-python solution I suggest following:

1. create an action with location keys. Each frame the action should contain a single spawn position. e.g frame 1 = position 1, frame 2 = position 2 ...
2. when you want to spawn an enemy

   2.a. create an random integer number in a property via random actuator.

   2.b you play the action frame at the emitter (empty) via Action Actuator in property mode (using the random property).

   2.c with a collision/ray/near/radar sensor check if the spawn point is empty. If so add an enemy and continue with 2. If not continue with 2.a